# SslStream, BEAST and TLS 1.1

Tags: .net, security, ssl, beast

With the recent advent of [BEAST](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/19/beast_exploits_paypal_ssl/) (exploits a vulnerability in SSL/TLS1.0 where the initial bytes of the payload are always the same) I looked into the [`SslStream` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) to see if it supported TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2, etc. It only [supports (`SslProtocol`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols.aspx) SSL 2 and 3 (which both predate TLS) and TLS 1.0.

Given that `SslProtocol` only advertises support for TLS 1.0 and below, is it at all possible to use `SslStream` for TLS 1.1 and beyond?

Comment: AFAIK there is limited/no support for TLS 1.1+ in clients, so therefore no servers bothered supporting it because TLS 1.0 has been "good enough" so far.  The pragmatic way of working around this exploit until better protocols are supported is to prefer a non-CBC cypher suite such as RC4, either on the client or the server.  See http://www.phonefactor.com/blog/slaying-beast-mitigating-the-latest-ssltls-vulnerability.php about the server side.  Not sure how to prefer a certain cypher on client side.

Comment: @Yoshi could you make an answer, doesn't seem like I will get any more and yours is pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an update is in order.

As of .NET 4.5, [SslProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols.aspx) (and consequently [SslStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx)) now supports TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.

These protocols are enabled by default in 4.6. For 4.5, you'll need to activate them in your `SslStream` object by using the overloaded `AuthenticateAsClient` call:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, null, SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11, true);
```